# Matplotlib cmap not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code for Python 3 which generates a wave function over time and plot the result in 3D. Notice that the `schroedinger1D(...)` function returns two numpy arrays, each of shape (36,1000).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# Initial conditions, outside for plotting.
f_re = lambda x: np.exp(-(x-xc)**2.0/s)*np.cos(2.0*np.pi*(x-xc)/wl)
f_im = lambda x: np.exp(-(x-xc)**2.0/s)*np.sin(2.0*np.pi*(x-xc)/wl)

def schroedinger1D(xl, xr, yb, yt, M, N, xc, wl, s):
    """
        Schrödinger Equation Simulation (no potential)
    """
    f = lambda x: f_re(x)**2 + f_im(x)**2
    area = fixed_quad(f, xl, xr, n=5)[0]
    f_real = lambda x: f_re(x)/area
    f_imag = lambda x: f_im(x)/area
    # Boundary conditions for all t
    l = lambda t: 0*t
    r = lambda t: 0*t
    # "Diffusion coefficient"
    D = 1
    # Step sizes and sigma constant
    h, k = (xr-xl)/M, (yt-yb)/N
    m, n = M-1, N
    sigma = D*k/(h**2)
    print("Sigma=%f" % sigma)
    print("k=%f" % k)
    print("h=%f" % h)
    # Finite differences matrix
    A_real = np.diag(2*sigma*np.ones(m)) + np.diag(-sigma*np.ones(m-1),1) + np.diag(-sigma*np.ones(m-1),-1)
    A_imag = -A_real
    # Left boundary condition u(xl,t) from time yb
    lside = l(yb+np.arange(0,n)*k)
    # Right boundary condition u(xr,t) from time tb
    rside = r(yb+np.arange(0,n)*k)
    # Initial conditions
    W_real = np.zeros((m, n))
    W_imag = np.zeros((m, n))
    W_real[:,0] = f_real(xl + np.arange(0,m)*h)
    W_imag[:,0] = f_imag(xl + np.arange(0,m)*h)
    # Solving for imaginary and real part
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        b_cond = np.concatenate(([lside[j]], np.zeros(m-2),[rside[j]]))
        W_real[:,j+1] =  W_real[:,j] + A_real.dot(W_imag[:,j]) - sigma*b_cond
        W_imag[:,j+1] =  W_imag[:,j] + A_imag.dot(W_real[:,j]) + sigma*b_cond
    return np.vstack([lside, W_real, rside]), np.vstack([lside, W_imag, rside])


xl, xr, yb, yt, M, N, xc, wl, s = (-9, 5, 0, 4, 35, 1000, -5, 4.0, 3.0)
W_real, W_imag = schroedinger1D(xl, xr, yb, yt, M, N, xc, wl, s)
[X, T] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xl, xr, M+1), np.linspace(yb, yt,N))
# Plot results
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("$x$", fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("$t$", fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel("$\Psi(x,t)$", fontsize=20)
print(X.shape)
print(T.shape)
print(W_real.T.shape)
surface = ax.plot_surface(X, T, W_real.T, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, 
                          antialiased=True, rstride=10, cstride=10)
fig.colorbar(surface)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output has the right shape for X, T and W_real.T (1000,36), however the surface has, as far as I understand, wrong assigned colors. I was expecting that the color varies in Z axis, but here I can't tell what is measuring:[image: Plot of wave function over time]

Comment: Would you be able to show the rest of the code?

Comment: This may be a real problem, a bug, or some problem with the input data; nobody can know without a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  added :)

Comment: @user2027202827 added. Please use python 3 for execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to understand what is happening when reducing the number of grid points

```
xl, xr, yb, yt, M, N, xc, wl, s = (-9, 5, 0, 4, 10, 10, -5, 4.0, 3.0)
```

and also using rstride and cstride of 1.

In this case the plot may look something like this

[image]

Now it's easy to spot the problem: The frequency of oscillations in your wavefunction is larger than the resolution of the grid. That means one single patch of the surface plot may start at a very low value and go up to a very high value. In this case, its color can be anything since it's determined by the value of one single edge of the patch. (If the patch starts at high value and goes down to a low value, it redder than if it starts at low value and goes up to a high value.)

The only possible solution is to make the grid more dense than the frequency of oscillations. I.e. try to visualize a wavefuction which is more smoothly variing, or visualize only part of the wavefunction but with a denser grid.

Comment: Got it, I changed the wavefunction to a smoother one and over a small domain (just to feel the changes) and I started to work with the grid and now I can see the colour variation correctly. Thanks